# How to place an element in top of another using CSS (without using absolute position)?

Tags: css

Is it possible to go from this:

```
 <h1>Logo</h1>

 <ul>Menu</ul>
```

to this:

```
 <ul>Menu</ul>

 <h1>Logo</h1>
```

with CSS and without using absolute or relative position?

Comment: How about move the HTML for the first element after the second element?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: @mellamokb I want to enable the user to change it by his own, with php variables that controls the CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could surround both of those blocks in a containing div, then float the logo to either side and give it a "clear: both", which should push it below the menu.

```
<div>
   <div>Logo</div>
   <div>Menu</div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div>
   <div style="float: right; clear: both">Logo</div>
   <div>Menu</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take is to use negative margins:

```
<style>
    h1 { margin-top: 100px; }
    ul { margin-top: -100px; }
</style>
```

This allows the markup to stay the same while allowing the elements to appear in a different order.

With the above CSS, you can go from this HTML:

```
<h1>Logo</h1>
<ul>...</ul>
```

To this using nothing more than CSS:

```
<ul>...</ul>
<h1>Logo</h1>
```

All the while ***without using*** `position: absolute` or `position: relative`.